# Community Bulletin

Tags: support, questions

There is a community bulletin section on the left side of the main page.  Is the only way to get questions on there to tag it under the featured tag?  I have seen questions that were asked by users with very little reputation that  still shows up there.

Comment: I may be wrong but these appear to be recent meta questions. I don't see any correlation with a users reputation, and wouldn't expect to see one. Low rep does not equal a poor question. But perhaps one of the other mods or SO employees has a better idea.

Comment: Mine is on the right side of the page.